# Функция date() выводит неправильное время

Tags: php

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:m:y');
var_dump($now);
```

Почему выводится неправильное время, притом одно и тоже, когда я обновляю страницу?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что m - месяц, y - год.

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
var_dump($now);
```